# Evaluate the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$

Comment: $$0\le\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x(x+1)}\le\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x}=0$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: When $x$ is big, what is $\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ close to? You undoubtedly know.

Comment: I can see how it would be close to 0, just curious as to how to evaluate it completely

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 4):

Although it's pretty obvious that $x(x+1)=x^2+x$ goes to infinity for $x\to\infty$, you can use partial fraction decomposition if it is not clear:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x(x+1)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({1\over x}-{1\over x+1}\right)=0$$

Comment: So I just set up $\frac{1}{x(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{1+x} $

Comment: And in this case A and B will both = 1?

Comment: $A=1$ and $B=-1$. You can obtain it by setting $$A(x+1)+Bx=1$$
After that compare coefficients and solve the system$$A+B=0\\A=1$$